# Select the largest number of records based on a date range. (that have dates within 6 months of eachother)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a list of dates.

I need to be able to select the largest number of records that are in within 6 months of eachother.

Then the next largest number of records and so on until all records are selected.

Here is the data

```
1  19-Oct-2007
2  03-Dec-2007
3  16-Oct-2009
4  26-Oct-2009
5  30-Oct-2009
6  01-Nov-2009
7  16-Nov-2009
8  30-Nov-2009
9  11-Dec-2009
10  25-Dec-2009
11  01-Jan-2010
12  21-Jan-2010
13  27-Jan-2010
14  28-Jan-2010
15  28-Jan-2010
16  12-Feb-2010
17  12-Feb-2010
18  27-Feb-2010
19  09-Mar-2010
20  22-Mar-2010
21  26-Mar-2010
22  01-Apr-2010
23  22-Oct-2010
24  15-Oct-2011
25  18-Oct-2011
26  26-Oct-2011
27  16-Nov-2011
28  18-Nov-2011
29  19-Nov-2011
30  26-Nov-2011
31  29-Nov-2011
32  29-Nov-2011
33  30-Nov-2011
34  06-Dec-2011
35  16-Dec-2011
36  17-Dec-2011
37  20-Dec-2011
38  28-Dec-2011
39  01-Jan-2012
40  01-Jan-2012
41  09-Jan-2012
42  13-Jan-2012
43  27-Jan-2012
44  01-Feb-2012
45  23-Feb-2012
46  29-Feb-2012
47  01-Mar-2012
48  01-Mar-2012
49  01-Mar-2012
50  02-Mar-2012
51  04-Mar-2012
52  04-Mar-2012
53  05-Mar-2012
54  05-Mar-2012
55  17-Mar-2012
56  23-Mar-2012
57  24-Mar-2012
58  01-Apr-2012
59  03-Apr-2012
60  04-Apr-2012
```

One possible solution would be to select

- records 24-60  (they are within 172 days of eachother)
- record  23     (its not within 6 months of the preceding/next dates)
- records 3-22   (they are within 167 days of eachother)
- recods 1-2     (They are within 45 days of eachother)

(I started at the largest date and selected backwards.  This is probably not the optimal solution)

Answer (score 2):

The following is an iterative approach to the problem, and presently I can't have a better suggestion than that. It should work, though:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT *, rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM data
),
marked AS (
  SELECT
    rnk,
    Date,
    GroupDate = date
  FROM ranked
  WHERE rnk = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    r.rnk,
    r.Date,
    GroupDate = CASE
      WHEN m.GroupDate > DATEADD(MONTH, 6, r.Date) THEN r.Date
      ELSE m.GroupDate
    END
  FROM ranked r
  INNER JOIN marked m ON r.rnk = m.rnk + 1
)
SELECT
  MinDate     = MIN(Date),
  MaxDate     = MAX(Date),
  [RowCount]  = COUNT(*),
  RangeLength = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(Date), MAX(Date))
FROM marked
GROUP BY
  GroupDate
ORDER BY
  GroupDate
```

That is,

1. The last date is taken and used both for range check and as a group marker.
2. Subsequent (preceding) dates are processed until one more than half a year earlier than the marker is encountered.
3. The found date becomes the new group marker, and the process continues from Step 1 until there's no more rows.

Before proceeding with the iterations, the rows are ranked. But if you have a column that is guaranteed to contain unique sequential values without gaps, you can use that column instead of the ranking numbers.

Here are the results it gives for the sample in the original post:

```
MinDate     MaxDate     RowCount     RangeLength
----------  ----------  -----------  -----------
2007-10-19  2007-12-03  2            45
2009-10-16  2010-04-01  20           167
2010-10-22  2010-10-22  1            0
2011-10-15  2012-04-04  37           172
```

The entire script, including the setup, can be found and played with [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93bd8/4).

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote this too early. It is not correct. It is a good try though.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is with this solution, but I'm keen to try and fix it, especially since you've already upvoted my answer.

Comment: try your query with these dates and it should be clear: (1, '2012-01-01'), (2, '2012-01-01'), (3, '2012-03-01'), (4, '2012-03-01'), (5, '2012-08-01')

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Thanks. I could see nothing wrong with the result I got, but then I thought maybe we understood the problem differently. I think I now see how you understand it (which may well be more correct than how I did). You think the query must *find* the largest subset of dates that are within 6 months from one another, don't you? Some clues in the original post, which I must have (dis)missed at first, do support this view. I think it could be possible to use a recursive CTE to find *one* (the largest) such subset. But finding all of them so far seems a much more complicated task.

Comment: I agree it is complicated. That is what i tried exactly that in my query and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select d1.date, count(*)
from dates as d1 with (nolock) 
join dates as d2 with (nolock) 
on datediff(mm,d2.date,d1.date) < 6 
group by d1.date  
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  I tested it on SQL 2008 R2.   What part did not work for you?

Comment: after you corrected the syntax, it is only the result that is wrong. Try the script from @andryM

Answer (score 1):

I used my own testdata, this is very complicated stuff. It may be easier to handle with a cursor. But i am not a big fan of cursors. I have given it my best shot:

```
declare @t table(record int, date datetime)
insert @t values(1,'19-Oct-2007'),
(2,'03-Dec-2007'),
(3,'2-may-2009'),
(4,'16-Oct-2009'),
(5,'26-Oct-2009'),
(6,'30-Oct-2009'),
(7,'01-Nov-2009'),
(8,'16-Nov-2009'),
(9,'30-Nov-2009'),
(10,'11-Dec-2009'),
(11,'11-Dec-2010'),
(12,'11-Dec-2010'),
(13,'11-Dec-2010')

;with a as
(
  select datediff(day, t1.date, t2.date) daysapart, 
  row_number() over (order by count desc) rn,
  b.count, 
         t1.record fromrecord, 
         t2.record torecord
  from @t t1
  join @t t2
  on t1.date <= t2.date 
     and dateadd(month, 6, t1.date) > t2.date 
     and t1.record <= t2.record
  cross apply (select count(*) count from @t where record between t1.record and t2.record) b
)
, b as
(
    select * from a where not exists 
    (select 1 from a b where (a.fromrecord between b.fromrecord and b.torecord
      or a.torecord between b.fromrecord and b.torecord)
      and a.rn > b.rn and not exists(select 1 from a c where 
      (b.fromrecord between c.fromrecord and c.torecord
      or b.torecord between c.fromrecord and c.torecord)
      and b.rn > c.rn))
)
select count, fromrecord, torecord, daysapart from b
```

Result:

```
count       fromrecord  torecord    daysapart
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
7           4           10          56
3           11          13          0
2           1           2           45
1           3           3           0
```

Comment: This is a bit mind-blowing, but it works! One (rather minor) nitpick I've got on your solution is this condition: `datediff(day, t1.date, t2.date) between 0 and 180`. I would really change it to this: `t2.date <= dateadd(month, 6, t1.date)`. Of course, it changes nothing except it makes the ranges more precisely 6 months. Fantastic solution, and the only one that actually solves the problem too, it seems.

Comment: @AndriyM thank you for your comment and the nice words. Well spotted on the date issue. I just woke up and logged in to change that because it bothered me. I otherwise never get up this early in the morning

Comment: Btw. This will not scale well with a large dataset

Answer (score 0):

I have considered

1. 6Months = 180 days
2. If the difference between dates is > 180 days then they will go down in the list.

Try this :

```
create table #list (id int, dt datetime  )
-- insert you data into #list

select s1.id as ID_1, s1.dt as Date_2 , s2.id as ID_2, s2.dt as Date_2 
,abs( datediff(day, s2.dt, s1.dt) ) diff_in_days
from #list s1 , #list s2 
order by  case when abs(datediff(day, s2.dt, s1.dt) ) > 180 then 1
else  abs(datediff(day, s2.dt, s1.dt)) end  desc
```

Comment: I tried your script and it didn't give a correct or remotely correct result. This is a correction from my earlier comment

Comment: @t-clausen.dk can you tell me  1> In the Given dataset of the question what should be my first row of output ?

Comment: For me the understanding is - in the dataset find the difference between dates which are with in 6M and order them descending.

Comment: so you assume the author wants 3600 rows as the result set ?

Comment: dont know ... can you specify what he wants ?

Comment: You can try my solution. That should illustrate what Luke is asking for